# Что может случиться с внешними библиотеками при переходе в строгий режим?

Tags: javascript

Хочу перейти в строгий режим в своём `app.js`, но в документации Mozilla читал, что это может пагубно повлиять на работу библиотек, но как - не сказано. Что такого может произойти при переходе в строгий режим и можно ли будет всё откатить? Хочу сделать переход с полным осознанием последствий.